# /etc/init.d/nginx restart as root fails but nginx -t won't tell anything

Tags: nginx

So Nginx is started in daemon mode, but root, as confirms this command:

```
root@test:/home/vagrant# ps -edf | grep nginx
root      7331     1  0 13:42 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  7333  7331  0 13:42 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

But if I:

```
root@test:/home/vagrant# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx [fail]
```

But when I run:

```
root@test:/home/vagrant# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

It's only when I go back to user `vagrant` that I get:

```
[13:46:58] vagrant@test:/home/vagrant $ nginx -t
2016/04/21 13:47:01 [emerg] 7390#7390: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

And if I:

```
root@test:/home/vagrant# ls -l /run/nginx.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Apr 21 13:45 /run/nginx.pid
```

So why won't nginx restart? What am I doing wrong? I mean, `root` not having enough permission doesn't make sense, does it?

And how come `sudo nginx -t` doesn't display any error message?

Comment: You can solve the problem with this solution http://serverfault.com/a/265626

Answer (score 0):

Have you this directive in your configuration file `user www www;` ?

If yes, does the user `www` (or whom you set) have access to the *pid file* and to the *site directories* ?

extra: if you need you can move the *pif file* using the `pid path;` directive.